# Running psql directly

Tags: postgresql, macos

I have psql at the following location:

```
$ /Applications/PostgreSQL/psql.app
```

When I double click the app icon, it runs the following command and opens it:

```
$ cd /Users/david/PostgreSQL/pg94;source pg94.env;bin/psql
Password:
```

It will then allow me to enter in the `psql` shell:

```
psql (9.4.18)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

How would I add this to my path so I can just type in `psql` and it will go directly into the shell? I have tried a few of the other answers, but they don't seem to help.

As a workaround, now I have just done:

```
alias psql="cd /Users/david/PostgreSQL/pg94;source pg94.env;bin/psql"
```

But is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following path worked for me:

```
export PATH="/Users/david/PostgreSQL/pg94/bin:$PATH"
```